# How to check if key pair in 2D array exists?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, multidimensional-array

I have this 2d array or struct

```
public struct MapCell
{
    public string tile;
}

public MapCell[,] worldMap;
```

But there's no way to check if key pair is exists in this array or not... No methods for that available.

I tried to do it like this

```
if (worldMap[tileX, tileY] != null) {
}
```

it doesnt work:

```
Error 1 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Warudo.MapCell' and '<null>'
```

and for

```
if (worldMap[tileX, tileY].tile != null) {
```

it doesn't work either (exception pops up when it hits non existing element).

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

So, how do I check if key pair is exists or not?

Comment: Do you have to use an array? Maybe a Collection class like Dictionary<T> would provide you the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo ummm, can it be used as 2d array? Will it provide checking method then?

Comment: And why are you using a struct?  Mutable structs are a bad idea...  I'd probably recommend a class here.

Comment: I don't think that you're getting an exception for a non-existent element.  How are you initializing `worldMap`?  The code you have posted shouldn't throw an exception unless you aren't initializing `worldMap` or you are trying to access an index outside the bounds of your array, but your `if` condition should always be true since a `struct` can never be equal to `null`.

Comment: @Lurler -1 Currently, I think the question is very misleading.  Please update your question to include the actual error you were getting and any initialization/manipulation you are doing to worldMap.

Comment: @Steven Oxley, I updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never mentioned which error you are getting -- array out of bounds or a null reference. If you are getting array out of bounds you should precede your null check with something along the lines of...

```
// make sure we're not referencing cells out of bounds of the array
if (tileX < arr.GetLength(0) && tileY < arr.GetLength(1))
{
    // logic
}
```

Of course, it's best to just store the maximum array bounds instead of getting their lengths each time.

I also second (third?) the recommendation for using a class and not a struct.

**Edit:** Are you ever actually initializing this field? You haven't included it in your code sample. For example `worldMap = new MapCell[100,100];`, and then fill up the array...

Comment: I do initialize it, of course. I thought that I don't have to include this part.

Comment: Generally it's best to include everything related to the issue at hand. Sometimes the issue is in a place you don't suspect, everyone has that issue from time to time :)

Comment: You may edit your question above to include the declarations, they might help us help you further.

Comment: Also, yeah, it works :) Thank you :)

upd: no, your answer already what was needed.

Comment: @Lurler Well, you could simply edit this question and add the missing details instead of letting us find our way in the dark. upd: Please consider updating your question so others who will read it later know what the problem was. Don't be ashamed of mistakes. ^^

Comment: ok, I did as you said :) I think it might me more clear if someone need to find an answer to this or similar question.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using an array of struct values, they always exist (once the array is constructed), but have their default value until you set them.

I would recommend using a class here instead of a struct.  This will allow you to check for null, as well as act more in an expected fashion if you're going to be changing values (which, given the names, I expect...)

That being said, you could check for whether the string within the struct is null:

```
if (worldMap[tileX, tileY].tile != null)
{
    // You've set the "tile" field inside of this "cell"...
```

This works because the default value of a struct is initialized with all references, including strings, to null.

Comment: No, tile doesn't have to be not empty, but array may not have, lets say tileX = 10, then it will pop up exception that this key doesn't exists.

Comment: @Lurler Please copy-paste the exact text you're getting for the error.  I don't see how it's possible that you would be getting a "Key doesn't exist" error.  "Index was outside the bounds of the array" would typically be the error you'd see.